# How to order router mapping pattern to be last java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have post mapping `/{slug}` in PostController and in `WebController` I have `/tos` mapping which cannot be accessed because it already mapped to my post controller.

Is there any way to check router mapping in the PostController the last?

Comment: what code did you try and what error did you get ?